# Como mostrar datos en un Textfield en javafx

Tags: javafx

Buenas quien me podria colaborar para mostrar datos de un textfield tengo este codigo y nada que me funciona.

Metodo verificar cliente

```
    public int existeCliente(String cliente) {

        // llamamos a la conexion bd
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection con = getConexionTemporal();
        // Preparamos la consulta
        String sql = "SELECT count(id_cliente) FROM cliente WHERE 
                          cli_cedula=?";
        try {
            // Traemos los datos de la bd
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, cliente);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            // Cargamos los resultados
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getInt(1);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            cerrarObjeto(con);
            cerrarObjeto(rs);
            cerrarObjeto(ps);

        }
        return 1;
    }
```

y en el controller esto tengo
// Metodo buscar cliente

```
@FXML
void buscarCliente(ActionEvent event) {
    SqlFacturar cliente = new SqlFacturar();
    // Validamos los campos que no esten vacios
            if (txt_cedula.getText().equals("")) {
                // validamos campos
                Validaciones.checkEmptyFields(txt_cedula);
            }else{
    if (cliente.existeCliente(txt_cedula.getText())==0) {
```

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
 "Cliente no existe, debe registrarlo!");

```
    }else{

        txt_nombre.setText(cli.getNombre());        
    }
}
}
```

muchas gracias el que me pueda colaborar.

Comment: ¿Depuraste cuál podría ser el problema?  Primero pon esto fuera de todos los condicionales, para que se ejecute siempre: `txt_nombre.setText("Prueba");`. y dentro del `if` pones algo como `txt_nombre.setText(cli.getNombre()+"Prueba");` Así sabrás que no es problema del `TextField` en sí. Si aparece el dato `Prueba`, entonces tendrás que depurar tus variables y revisar tus métodos. Si no aparece, entonces tendrás que revisar cómo estás identificando el `TextField`.

Comment: gracias por reponder, hice su sugerencia y en el campo textfiel nombre me coloca prueba y no me carga el dato de la base de datos.

Comment: Correcto, veo que aquí `if (cliente.existeCliente(txt_cedula.getText())==0) {` preguntas si es igual a `0`, pero en realidad, cuando un cliente no existe, no le indicas que devuelva `0`. La cuestión de la BD es mejorable, pero por ahora prueba a modificarlo así: **`int idCliente=0; if (rs.next()) { idCliente=rs.getInt(1);} return idCliente;`** Así devolverá `0` cuando no encuentre registros.

Comment: amigo en la consulta traigo los datos de la bd con el sysou me muestra que si los trae, lo que no he podido es pasarlos al controller para mostrarlos en los textfield hice sysou en el controller y me sale null osea que no los esta pasando y no se como e buscado por internet y nada.

Comment: Me parece que tienes el programa planteado con un error de lógica. En vez de invocar un `SELECT count(id_cliente) FROM cliente WHERE cli_cedula=?` puedes crear una consulta que te devuelva todos los datos del cliente. Verificas si esa consulta trae datos, si los trae devuelves tu objeto `Cliente` con todos los datos. En caso de que no encuentre datos, puedes devolver siempre un objeto `Cliente`, pero vacío o con alguna clave `NULL` o `0`. Entonces verificas si el objeto tiene esa clave `NULL` o no para saber si la consulta arrojó datos.

Comment: asi cambie la consulta

String sql = "SELECT id_cliente, cli_nombre, cli_apellidos FROM 

cliente WHERE cli_cedula=?";

   try {
    // Traemos los datos de la bd

    ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, cliente);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();

    // Cargamos los resultados

    if (rs.next()) {

     rs.getString("cli_nombre");
     rs.getString("cli_apellidos");
     System.out.println(rs.getString("cli_nombre")+rs.getInt(1)+rs.getString("cli_apellidos"));
     return rs.getInt(1);

    }

Comment: Lo que he querido decir es que deberías hacer algo como mapear el resultado obtenido de la base de datos en una instancia de un objeto `Cliente`. O sea, llenar el objeto `Cliente` con los resultados obtenidos y devolver ese objeto. No sé si me entiendes. En vez de `return rs.getInt(1);` devolver un objeto `Cliente` con todos los datos. Entonces, podrás recuperar cualquier valor de dicho objeto. El problema es que así lo único que podrás leer en el destino es el valor de la columna 1 y nada más.